# Can not truncate / clear error.log on apache, but can do it manually with nano

Tags: log-files, apache-2.4

I tried to clear the content of error.log file on my apache server with commands

```
sudo >error.log

sudo truncate -s0 error.log
```

But in both cases I got `-bash: error.log: Permission denied`.

I tried the same thing while stopping apache, but still got the same message. After that I tried to clear it with `sudo nano error.log` and was able to remove everything.

So why was not I able to clear the log properly?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should try this :

```
sudo sh -c ">/var/log/apache2/error.log"
```

Comment: Can you please explain what does this command do?

Comment: It runs an inline `sh` (shell) command under `sudo` context. Actually this inline `sh` command clears Apache error log (as you know)

Comment: Thanks, but do you have any idea why I was not able to do this with >error.log?

Comment: My guess is that `>` is not a command without an interpreter like `sh` or `bash`

Comment: However your `sudo truncate...` command should work...That is the real thing i cannot explain by now

Comment: Redirection operators are evaluated by your local shell before the sudo command even runs. `sudo > foo` opens the file foo for writing, **then** runs the command `sudo `.  If you put it inside quotes or escape the redirection operator, then it is evaluated within the context of the sub-shell.